# For what values of b does the system have no solutions?

Tags: education

Help me please with system.

It turned out this way:
Multiply system 2

4x + by = 4

2bx + 2y = 4

The system has no solutions if:

4x + by ≠ 2bx + 2y

x (4 - 2b) ≠ y (2 - b)

2x (2 - b) ≠ y (2 - b)

For any b ≠ 2, the system will have only one solution.

And when b = 2 - infinite number of solutions:

4x + 2y = 4

2x + y = 2

Does it mean that for any b there will be such that the system has no solution?

It seems to me that when b = -2 will not solutions ....

[The system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zMti.jpg)

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

You have the following system with $b\not = 0$:
$$4x+by=4\Rightarrow y=-\frac{4}{b}x+\frac{4}{b}$$
$$2bx+2y=4\Rightarrow y=-bx+2 $$
These equations are the equations of two straight lines with slopes $λ_1=-\frac{4}{b}$ and $λ_2=-b$.
These two straight lines have no solution when they do not intersect, meaning that they are parallel. Hence must:

$$λ_1=λ_2\Rightarrow -\frac{4}{b}=-b\Rightarrow b^2=4\Rightarrow b=-2 \ or \ b=2$$

When $b=2$ the two equations have infinite solutions, hence it's rejected.
So $b=-2$.

If $b=0$ then $x=2 \ and \ y=2$.

So after all the only solution to the problem is $b=-2$

Comment: Thank you for another solve! It's really useful to see another way to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is correct indeed the system is

- $4x+by=4$
- $bx+y=2$

and for $b=-2$

- $4x-2y=4\implies 2x-y=2$
- $-2x+y=2\implies 2x-y=-2$

We can solve the problem in a more sistematic way by the RREF on the augmented matrix, that is

$$\left[ {\begin{array}{rr|r}
4&b&4\\
b&1&2\\
\end{array} } \right]\to \left[ {\begin{array}{rr|r}
4b&b^2&4b\\
4b&4&8\\
\end{array} } \right]\to \left[ {\begin{array}{rr|r}
4b&b^2&4b\\
0&4-b^2&8-4b\\
\end{array} } \right]$$

and thus the system has no solution for

- $4-b^2=0\implies b=\pm 2$
- $8-4b\neq 0\implies b\neq2$

that is precisely $b=-2$.

Comment: You are welcome! Bye

Comment: @Ариадна Recall that you can consider to accept an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work